# Every maximal subgroup has prime index.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, sylow-theory, solvable-groups, maximal-subgroup

> Let $G$ be finite group, and assume that every maximal subgroup of $G$
> has prime index.
>
> Show that $G$ is solvable.

I tried to prove it myself, but I'm afraid there may be mistakes in my proof.

$\textit{Proof:}$

To begin with, let's use the fact that

> If all maximal subgroups of $G$ have a prime index, then there is a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, where $p$ is the largest prime divisor of $|G|$.

I will leave this without proof, since this statement is easy to prove.

We prove this statement by using induction on the number of distinct prime divisors of order $G$. Let $n$ be the number of distinct prime divisors of $|G|$.

If $n = 1$, then this is true (for example, because any $p$-group is nilpotent).

Now let $|G| = p_1^{\alpha_1} \ldots  p_n^{\alpha_n}.$ Without limiting generality, we can assume that $p_1 < p_2 < \ldots < p_n$.

Then, using the above fact, there exists normal $S\in{\rm Syl}_{p_n}(G)$. Then $(|S|, |G:S|) = 1$ and since $S$ is normal, by the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem, we can conclude that $S$ has a complement $H$ in $G$.

$S$ is solvable, and $|H|$ has fewer distinct prime divisors than $|G|$ $\Rightarrow$ by induction assumption $H$ is solvable, but at the same time $H\cong G/S\Rightarrow S$ and $G/S$ are solvable $\Rightarrow G$ is solvable. $\blacksquare$

Comment: You have not argued why $H$ must have the same property.
It is more simple to argue for this on the quotient of $G$.

Comment: Yes, of course! I completely forgot to check it out.

This is done because for any maximal subgroup $M < G$ it is true that $M/S < G/S \Rightarrow \frac{|G/S|}{|M/S|}=|G :M|$ is a prime number?

Comment: It seems to me that everything is correct. Only one remark. If the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal, then it is unique, so it seems strange to write "there exists normal $S\in Syl_{p}(G)$".

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I didn't notice it.